# When can I use colons?

Tags: ruby, symbols

For the following line of code,

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 100 }
```

when do I use the colon with space then symbol, or symbol colon and then space?

e.g `validates :name`    and   `presence: true`

I don't understand the difference.

Comment: You are confused between a symbol(`:name`) and key notation(`presence:` or `:presence =>`) of a hash

Answer (score 3):

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 100}
```

is in turn:

```
validates(:name, **{presence: true, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 100}})
```

where `:name` is a first [`Symbol`] parameter to call to `validates` method, and the double-splatted hash having keys `:presence` and `:length` is a second parameter.

`Hash` in modern Ruby might be declared with a colon notation:

```
 {a: 42}
```

which is the same as

```
{:a => 42}
```

Also, for double-splatted hash parameter curlies might be omitted.